# "Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile

Trying to create a build of a flutter project through Xcode:-

**On selecting “Automatically Manage Signing:** I am getting the following error message

*("Runner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor).*

However; I have already given appropriate Team / Bundle Identifier & Signing Certificate. While Profile is being given by Xcode as “Xcode Manage Profile”.

**If I uncheck the automatically Manage Signing option** & gives a Provisioning Profile having distribution certificate. It still gives the error:-

“Provisioning profile "Final" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: XXXX Tech Limited (N5TXXXXKY9)”.

Comment: Same here. Did u solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I selected a "target" (im not sure what this means) instead of my project from the drop down, and I now have some different "Signing" options. Still no option for Automatic though. However there is a dropdown that says "Provisioning Profile : None"

so I will try and load my provisioning profile into there and see if that works, will report back. Thanks for the continued assistance KMT much appreciated.

edit: So that seemed to move me along to a new error. "No signing certificate "iOS Development" found".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).